# Turtle module crashes when using counter on while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
from turtle import *
import tkinter

r = 0
shapes = [shape("square"), shape("turtle"), shape("triangle")]

def hello():
    while True:
        right(100)
        forward(100)
        left(100)
        r +=1
        
        

hello()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

whenever i remove `r +=1` it works fine. But as soon as I add it, it crashes. The main reason as to why I wanted to use a counter was because originally my code looked like this:

```
from turtle import *
import tkinter

r = 0
shapes = [shape("square"), shape("turtle"), shape("triangle")]

def hello():
    while True:
        right(r)
        forward(r)
        left(r)
        r +=1
        
        

hello()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

But that makes the program crash even faster, funny enough. Anyone having similar problems?

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: No, the window just closes down. I guess you could call it a "crash". Thanks to the tkinter module I can keep the window open and close it down anytime i want. But the counter hinders me from doing that

Comment: It is because exception "*UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment"* is raised.  Add `global r` at the beginning of `hello()`.  BTW, you should use `after()` instead of while loop.

Comment: Probably better to move `r = 0` inside the function, as it isn't used anywhere else.  It doesn't need to be global.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has a couple of issues, besides `r` not being declared `global`.  First, it's an infinite loop so your counter will never be examined.  Second, it imports tkinter needlessly.  Let's rework your code so it's no longer loops forever but instead returns the value of counter once the turtle wanders outside your window:

```
from turtle import *

def hello():
    counter = 0

    width, height = window_width(), window_height()

    while -width/2 < xcor() < width/2 and -height/2 < ycor() < height/2:
        right(counter)
        forward(counter)
        left(counter)

        counter += 1

    return counter

print(hello())

mainloop()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
31
>
```